# How do I include processed page content in a Wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to include a *processed* page within another page?

E.g., in a template, we write
$page_data = get_page( ... page ID here ... );

and we would like the page content AFTER its template has generated the content

So e.g., when we use

echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);

we only get the page content, we would like the whole page (wrapper, header, footer etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/page-B" style="border:none;width:100%;height:600px;"></iframe>
```

to display the whole *page-B* inside *page-A*.

You could also check out `wp_remote_get()` and `wp_remote_retrieve_body()` to fetch remote content:

```
$the_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get('http://example.com/page-B') );
```

The transients API gives you the possibility to cache the results for some `$timetolive` seconds, with:

```
set_transient( 'my_page_b', $the_body, $timetolive );
```

where you can fetch it with

```
get_transient( 'my_page_b' );
```

### Resources:

http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_retrieve_body

http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API